# What is this atom affect called?

Tags: style-identification

I've seen lots of websites with these types of effects/design in the background. What is it called?

[image]

Source: https://www.simpla.io/

Comment: I don't think my comment would make  a correct answer but I wanted to point out that the javascript library to create that effect is [particles.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js).

Comment: You should look at this question. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/73654/arbitrarily-dotted-images-that-simulate-depth/73660#73660

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe called a **Network Graph** diagram, and it's associated with a the mathematical graph theory

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

That said, I'm not sure if there might be perhaps a more Graphic Design naming for it.

Edit:
Here's an example of a javascript library to create one:

http://christophergandrud.github.io/d3Network/

It also seems to use the term **Network Graph**, so that's your best  bet.